# I am using AJAX and PHP and the console keeps on saying cannot read property documentElement

Tags: javascript, ajax

So here is the code and I got it from a tutorial but when I actually run it, it gave me an uncaught error which says

> cannot read property 'documentElement' of null handleServerResponse

Here's the Javascript file:

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
    var xmlHttp;

    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }

    if (!xmlHttp)
        alert("Cannot create object!");
    else
        return xmlHttp;
}

function express() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        word = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("input").value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "chuffbucket.php?word=" + word, true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    else {
        setTimeout('express()', 1000);
    }
}

function handleServerResponse(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data
            document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = '<span style="color: blue">' + message + '</span>';
            setTimeout('express()', 1000);
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("No chalk in the house!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the `onreadystatechange` event, not a timer.

Comment: But I did. On the express function.

Comment: So you did. Although your pattern is very bizarre. Try using [this manner](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-javascript.php) instead.

Comment: Now it's not even saying there's an error. It just does nothing. @RoryMcCrossan kindly help.